# Find last word in string without any dots, white spaces

Tags: preg-match

I dont understant regular expression, because it seems very dificult... So what i found it just find last word with dots and etc.

```
$content='Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.';
$pattern = '/[^ ]*$/';
preg_match($pattern, $content, $result);
echo $result[0];
```

I get "leo.".

How can I get just "leo", without dot, or question mark ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the last word using the `$` anchor and a lookahead:

```
$pattern = '~[a-z]+(?=[^a-z]*$)~i';
```

explanation:

```
~           # pattern delimiter
 [a-z]+     # all characters between a and z (included) one or more times
 (?=        # open a lookahead. Means followed by:
    [^a-z]* # all characters that are not letters zero or more times
    $       # until the end of the string
 )          # close the lookahead
~           # pattern delimiter
i           # case insensitive ( [a-z] => [a-zA-Z] and [^a-z] => [^a-zA-Z])
```

For your regex tries, i suggest you to use this [online tool](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) which is specific to php.

Comment: Thank you very much, it ofcorse working, I will try to learn the regular expressions. Thanks for suggested web site!

Comment: The delimiter i can replace "~" with "/" or not ?

Comment: @user1139767: You can use `~` `#` `/` `|` .... but don't forget to escape the character you choose if you use it as literal in the pattern. Note that in the online tool the delimiter is `/`, thus you must escape all the `/` in the pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to get First and last word of string ant to put them into array ? for example array( 'first' => Nullam, 'last' => leo), I am thinking about this: $pattern='~(?<first>[a-z]+(?=[^a-z]))(?<last>[a-z]+(?=[^a-z]*$))~iu'; but not working ..

Comment: And this pattern not working well for example if string contains of utf8 characters, the preg_match cuts off... for example: $content='Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo Čiękas.'; The rezult is: "kas". The pattern is: ''~[a-z]+(?=[^a-z]*$)~iu';
'

Comment: `Č` and `ę` are not letters between a and z in the unicode table: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use rubular.com to learn and test regular expressions. They also provide a nice cheat-sheet =).

You will catch your word with : \b([a-zA-Z]*)[\W]$

With this regex, you will match the point too. To extract only "leo" you will need to understand about capturing groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I solved this problem with pattern: '/[\p{L}\d]+(?=[^a-z]*$)/u'. Maybe someone know how to find first and last word in string and put them in ,  arrays with preg_match ?